# Java how to remove fields into a String value?

Tags: java, android, string, substring, iso

Good afternoon, I would like to know what is the easiest function that would fix my problem.

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int received = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

            messageFromServer = new String(buffer, 0, received); //     F108102200000002E00002940001...
```

the String MessageFromServer receives a value from the server via a socket, and I would like to treat that message excluding the first 2 characters of it. In addition to, for example, excluding the string in the field (33 to 40) (EXAMPLE). I saw the replace function but I don't know if it is the best one to use, could someone answer me by passing an example? Thank you.

Comment: `messageFromServer.substring(2)`. Be careful to use an explicit charset with `new String(...)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner did not change the message, it continues to print it. Any question?

Comment: Strings are *immutable*, you need to store result of `substring` somewhere as it is new string object. Maybe something like `messageFromServer = messageFromServer.substring(2);`.

Comment: `new String(buffer, 2, received)`

Comment: @blackapps `received-2`. And you're assuming it's a single-byte encoding.

Comment: @Andy Turner, thank you, yes. And if not OP would get the idea.